# Desencadenar la tecla ENTER después de doble clic a celda en Grid

Tags: c#

De antemano buen día a todos; recurro por una duda que tengo y espero y agradezco me puedan ayudar. La aplicación que tengo cuenta con un GRID y un TEXTBOX. La pequeña aplicación solicita un código de producto en el TEXTBOXy al dar enter lo envía al GRID, sin embargo la primera columna del GRID contiene los códigos de productos alternos que tiene el código principal, pero requiero que al dar doble clic a la primera columna me envíe el código al TEXTBOX y en automático me debe enviar un ENTER sin necesidad de recurrir al teclado. Lo que me falta es que se desencadene el ENTER, he buscado ejemplos pero no me han funcionado. Aquí mi cpodigo:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Clave")
        {
            txtClaveProducto.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            //SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
        }
    }
```

Para que me funcione tengo que posicionarme al fin del último carácter del TEXTBOX para que me de la información. Ya tengo la aplicación adaptada para que al dar enter envíe la información al GRID, lo que me falta es que se desencadene el ENTER. Gracias por su valioso apoyo. Saludos

Comment: A ver si me aclaro, lo que quieres es que al darle doble click en el `Grid` , este envié el valor al `TextoBox` y este a su vez genere un Enter?

Comment: En qué control requerís que se ejecute el enter?

Comment: Hola gracias por contestar. Efectivamente. Al dar doble clic sobre la celda envía el contenido al textbox, pero requiero que después de enviar la información al textbox, se ejecute de manera automática el ENTER en el textboc. En el código que agrego envío la información del GRID al textbox, pero tengo que darle manualmente el enter para que se ejecute una función después de dar clic en ENTER, pero deseo que se haga de manera automáica. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Es un ejemplo clásico de para qué sirve escribir *funciones*; la solución es muy sencilla, pasa por escribir un mejor código. Me explico:

En lugar de atar una funcionalidad a un evento, en este caso, un teclazo al `Enter`, lo que debes hacer es escribir una función que haga lo que quieres, y esa función invocarla ante un evento, por ejemplo:

```
private void AcciónDelTextbox()
{
    /* Tu código */
}

private void txt_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        AcciónDelTextbox();
    }
}

private void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Clave")
    {
        txtClaveProducto.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        AcciónDelTextbox();
    }
}
```

Existen muchos "trucos" para escribir un mejor código, todos comenzamos sin conocerlos o sin darles la importancia debida, pero cuando nos enfrentamos a problemas así de minúsculos es cuando salen a relucir. Te dejo una página de [consejos y buenas prácticas en programación](https://personales.unican.es/sanchezbp/teaching/faqs/programming.html)  (¡existen muchos más!) para que le des una leída y busques en qué puedes mejorar tus códigos. Dedicarse a esto es nunca dejar de aprender. ¡Saludos!

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario. Claro que trucos hay y muchos y aplica a todos los temas de la vida, sin embargo habemos quienes nos iniciamos y con la práctica es como nos haremos de la experiencia y todo a lo que mecionas. Gracias por tus recomendaciones. Saludos cordiales

Comment: Es justo lo que digo; aquí estamos primero para aprender y después para intentar ayudar. Solo con la experiencia aprendes a detectar "malas prácticas" porque, vamos, ¿cuántas veces no pasé por lo mismo? No quise sonar rudo, pero sí me pareció importante recalcar lo de las buenas prácticas. Sé bienvenido ;)

Comment: Gracias. Logré resolver mi problema con tus consejos. Saluditos cordiales